# Why permit params in controllers are protected in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, strong-parameters

I see two difference experience in rails. In multiple projects `permit_params`
are defined in `protected` and in multiple projects they are defined in `private`

What is the difference between these two strategies?

Please explain briefly

Comment: I think when we create an gem or plugin where we will allowed user to inherit controller in this case we should use protected other wise should be private

Comment: It doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0):

**private**

The type or member can only be accessed by code in the same class.

**protected**

The type or member can only be accessed by code in the same class or struct, or in a derived class.

An example of a private method:
http://matthodan.com/2010/08/08/ruby-private-methods-vs-protected-methods.html